# Mapping dependencies/requirements for GCP APIs/services

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Does anyone knows a way to map the dependencies or requirements of any GCP API?
E.g. enabling `container.googleapis.com` would automatically enable `compute.googleapis.com` and others into a same chart/table/text/anything.

The GCP docs don't specify any such dependency for any API (from what I have seen so far). So I'm either looking for a Doc which specifies this, a gcloud command or a completely different tool that can help mapping it.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have any public external documentation around service dependencies for now. therefore please open a FR  in refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list)

Answer (score 1):

did you open a Feature Request as suggested ? If so, can you share the link ?

As a faint consolation, you can have a look at this [article](https://binx.io/blog/2020/10/03/how-to-find-google-cloud-platform-service-dependencies/) from which we can tell that the API interdependency information was once available through the serviceusage API.

There you'll find a diagram as of october 2020 (see screenshot bellow)

[image: GCP API dependency diagram excerpt]

Answer (score 1):

One workaround could be to use the [Service Usage API](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest). The [disable method](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services/disable) has a `disableDependentServices` field which disables all services that depend on the services being disabled.

You could enable a bunch of services in GCP, disable a service, and observe which dependent services are also disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I did end up opening a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241456145) for this and the fact that I had to do so still boggles the mind.